# Search for a word within a file that has a specific modified date

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, I need to interrogate a log file for a specific word i.e 'error' ensuring that I am searching the most recent log (date modified of today).

I have so far tried the `Get-Child`, `Where-Object` and `Select-String` cmdlet's but I'm having real trouble stringing it all together.

I have the following to find a log or txt file from within a directory that has a date modified of 'today':

```
dir c:\temp\ -i *.txt, *.log -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date)::today}
```

and the following to search the same directory for any files that contain the word 'error':

```
dir c:\temp\ -i *.txt, *.log -Recurse |
    Select-String error
```

I would like to incorporate the two queries I already have so that I search the directory for the latest file and then search that latest file for the word 'error'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the latest log file, I'd suggest sorting your list and picking off the last one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:TEMP -Include *.txt, *.log -Recurse |
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -ge ([datetime]::Today) |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Select-String -Pattern error
```

Comment: @RickyBriggs Glad to help!  One improvement would be to assign the call to a variable before using `Select-String` just to make sure you actually have files from that day and aren't getting false negatives.